# Parsing a graph from a dot notation input for Dijkstra's Algorithm C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph, split, dijkstra

I am trying to read a graph from a text file and parse it to be able to extract the vertices, edges and weight to use for a Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation.

The text file contains the following structure:

```
graph {
    a -- b[label="5",weight="5"];
    a -- c[label="1",weight="1"];
    c -- b[label="3",weight="3"];
    c -- e[label="1",weight="1"];
    e -- b[label="1",weight="1"];
}
```

Finding it difficult to use the .split since the data is not seperated by the same delimeter.

I need to extract for example from the first line:
a needs to be set as from.
b needs to be set as to
and 5 needs to set as weight

Any ideas on how I can approach this please?

Comment: You could pick one of the parser libraries out there, or you could just use a RegEx. You can also use Split repeatedly: split by `[`, split first result by `--`, ...

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the values easily using this regular expression:

```
(\w+) -- (\w+)\[label="(\w+)",weight="([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"\];
```

Full Code:

```
string rawData = File.ReadAllText("H:\\data.txt");
string pattern = "(\\w+) -- (\\w+)\\[label=\"(\\w+)\",weight=\"([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)\"\\];";
var matches = Regex.Matches(rawData, pattern);
```

**Edit:** 
Here's how we can get the different values from each match object

Define an `Edge` class just for holding data

```
class Edge {
    public string NodeALabel;
    public string NodeBLabel;
    public double Weight;
    public string EdgeLabel;
}
```

Get the group values from each match. The group number is determined by how many opening parenthesis there are on the left side of the group.

```
var edgeList = matches.Select(match => new Edge() {
    NodeALabel= match.Groups[1].Value,
    NodeBLabel= match.Groups[2].Value,
    Weight= double.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value),
    EdgeLabel= match.Groups[3].Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Love regex. Can you also demonstrate how to extract the matched parts? (I know, I could just look up the reference, but you said "Full" code, didn't you? ;-) )

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica Will add it in a few minutes.

Comment: This is great @Anonta! Did not know I could use regex for this! Thanks

Comment: @Anonta What references are you using for the `Regex.Matches` part since when trying to implement your code it's giving me an error on the `matches.Select` as follows: 'Match Collection' does no contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Match Collection' could be found

Comment: @AvrilFenech `System.IO`, `System.Linq` and `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: @Anonta Yep got the same ones! Still getting an error :/

Comment: @AvrilFenech This error is shown when `System.Linq` is not imported.

Comment: @Anonta Yeah. I have it but still it's giving that same issue. Will look into it further.